# how to get the acquired index from Semaphore

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, semaphore

I have an array of int with size 4, only one thread can access an array cell at a time.
I thought about using Semaphore but I don't know how or if there is a way to get the acquired index
I build a code example to explain butter:

```
public class Temp {

    private ExecutorService executeService;
    private Semaphore semaphore;
    private int[] syncArray; // only one thread can access an array cell at the same time

    public Temp() {
        syncArray = new int[]{1,2,3,4};
        executeService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        semaphore = new Semaphore(syncArray.length, true);

        for(int i = 0;i < 100; i++) {
            executeService.submit(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    semaphore.acquire();

                    // here I want to access one of the array cell
                    // dose not matter witch one as long as no other thread is currently use it
                    int syncArrayIndex = semaphore.getAcquiredIndex(); // is something like this possible?
                    syncArray[syncArrayIndex] += ...;

                    semaphore.release();
                }
            });
        }

    }
}
```

Edit:
this is a piece of code that looks closer the my real problem:

```
public class Temp {

    private ExecutorService executeService;
    private Semaphore semaphore;
    private static ChromeDriver driver;

    public Temp() {
        executeService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    }

    public Future<WikiPage> getWikiPage(String url) {
        executeService.submit(new PageRequest(url) {

        });
    }

    private static class PageRequest implements Callable<WikiPage> {
        String url;
        public PageRequest(String url) {
            this.url = url;
        }
        @Override
        public WikiPage call() throws Exception {
            String html = "";
            synchronized (driver) {
                html = ...// get the wiki page, this part takes a log time
            };
            WikiPage ret =  ...// parse the data to the WikiPage class
                            // this part takes less time but depend on the sync block above

            return ret;
        }
    }
}
```

@Kayaman I'm not sure I understand your comment, the problem is that I return a future. Do you have a any suggestions on how to improve my code to run faster?

Comment: "permits" are not identifyable. You can't use a single `Semaphore` for individual access to 4 different objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, semaphore isn't useful here. It only knows about how many permits it has, there are no "indices" in a semaphore.

You can use [AtomicIntegerArray](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicIntegerArray.html) instead, although if you explain your root problem, there may be a more suitable class to use.

Comment: I'm using a chromeDriver in selenium to get a Wikipedia page, get the part I need from the chromeDriver is takeing alot longer then the processing I do with the data. So I wanted to use 4 chromeDrivers on 4 diffrent wikipedia pages at the same time

Comment: @roni then you might want to do something like putting the scraped data in a queue, and the processor would take from the queue, process and store. A shared `int[]` with a `Semaphore` is definitely the wrong way to go.

Comment: i'm not sure I understand your answer in 100% so I added a code that is closer the my real code, I would like if you could give me an opinion on what you think.

Comment: @roni well, you're synchronizing on `driver`, making the code single threaded. That's the main issue you have. You need a driver per thread if you want any improvement.

Comment: I know but driver a thread is not an option, that is why I want 4 drivers to all the threads. Is that possible?

Comment: @roni you mean pooling the drivers? It's possible, but I don't see why you wouldn't just use 4 threads and driver for each one. Since the driver is the limited resource, 10 threads is overkill when only 4 drivers are available.